# How to Bind Store in GridPanel

Tags: extjs, ext.net

i am newbie in EXT.NEt control .... 
i hv created a gridpanel during the design time and 
after that i hv created one Ext.data.Store in javascript at run time and fill the data.
now how can i bind this store to gridpanel in javascript.

GridPanel during the design time....

```
   <ext:GridPanel ID="gridpanel" runat="server" MinWidth="1000" MinHeight="400" ForceFit="true">
        <TopBar>
            <ext:Toolbar ID="Toolbar1" runat="server">
                <Items>
                    <ext:ToolbarFill ID="ToolbarFill1" runat="server" />
                    <ext:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text=" Export" Icon="PageExcel">
                        <Listeners>
                            <Click Handler="submitValue(#{gridpanel}, #{FormatType}, 'xls');" />
                        </Listeners>
                    </ext:Button>
                </Items>
            </ext:Toolbar>
        </TopBar>
        <ColumnModel>
            <Columns>
                <ext:Column ID="Col8" runat="server" Text="Project" DataIndex="Project"></ext:Column>
            </Columns>
            <Columns>
                <ext:Column ID="Col1" runat="server" Text="Parcel" DataIndex="Parcel"></ext:Column>
            </Columns>                
        </ColumnModel>           
    </ext:GridPanel>
```

Now i create store in javascript

```
   var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            storeId: 'mapList',
            fields: ['project', 'parcel'],
            autoLoad: true,
            pageSize: 10,
            data: listdata,
            proxy: {
                type: 'memory',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'items'
                }
            }
        });
        var ExtGridPanel = Ext.getCmp('ContentPlaceHolder1_gridpanel');
```

Now how can i bind this store to our gridPanel

Comment: As I know - it is not possible to generate grid without store and set it later. During grid creation you need provide a correct store. Why you don't want to generate grid on js side?

Comment: Hi @Andron thank you for response .. i tried to create the grid at javascript and that is working but paging is not working . i given the pagesize as 10 but it is not taking and showing all the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grid.reconfigure(store, [columns])` to change which store is bound to the grid.

Comment: thanks @Neil that is working. is it possible to bind the store in javascript. actually i change my question littel bit. During the design time i given grippanel and store and In javascript i want to bind that store because my result is coming in javascript.

  var ExtGridPanel = Ext.getCmp('ContentPlaceHolder1_gridpanel');
            if (ExtGridPanel != null) {
                var ExtStore = ExtGridPanel.getStore();
                ExtStore.load(listdata);
            }
This load function is not working , what else i can try...